# How to use double-float?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am struggling a little trying to figure out how to tell Lisp that I want to use double-float values. Suppose I have:

```
(let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0)))
```

Which gives:

```
0.33333334
```

If I want to use double-float, I tried this:

```
(let ((x 1)) (declare (type double-float x)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0)))
0.33333334
```

So the result is not a double-float. I can, however, force double-float like this:

```
(let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0d0)))
0.3333333333333333d0
```

And now I get a double-float result.

So my question is: if I'm defining a form or function in which I want arithmetic to be in double-float, how do I establish that? I've read lots of online resources on using `declare`, `proclaim`, etc, but haven't been able to apply it to getting the result I'm after. I'm not convinced I know how to utilize these in this context, or even if they are the correct mechanism to use.

Same question would apply if I were trying to do `long-float` or anything else that isn't the default.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9521593/1193075

Comment: @uselpa that's a great link, but it doesn't really answer my question. It indeed tells me what `declare` means, but doesn't tell me how to do what I'm wanting to do: which is to assure that the variables/calculations are double-float rather than the default.

Comment: Yes that's why it's a comment and not an answer ;-)

Comment: @uselpa that's cool. Although "just a link" wouldn't be a suitable answer according to SO guidelines anyway. ;) Seriously, I am very glad you provided that link as it does explain some things that I wasn't totally gathering from the online documentation I was reading.

Comment: it's a bit different in CL - i.e. the opposite of what you expected (I  think). when you `declare` something to be a certain type, *you* are telling the compiler that ***you*** will take care for that variable to contain that specific type of value. The compiler won't take any actions to ensure this, on the contrary, it will *assume* that the type *is* as declared. Next, understand *contagion* - as the quote in Rainer Joswig's answer describes. :)

Comment: Thanks @WillNess, I was, in fact, just reading a little something about "contagion" (relative to Lisp). I shall investigate further.

Comment: @WillNess so in CL that if I had a function that did some calculations based upon parameters, and it had no constants in it, then unless I used `coerce` everywhere, it would determine precision based upon the precision of the parameters that I pass? And if those are variables, then the precision of those would depend upon what how those were previously computed?

Comment: yes, though not necessarily everywhere but in some strategic places. The data  type "contagion" (maybe it's a C terminology? I don't remember) is just what the quote shown by Rainer is saying: a float "infects" an otherwise ints-only expression: `[1]> (/ 1 7) => 1/7` `[2]> (/ 1 7.0) => 0.14285715`. And "precision" is a whole other game, you'd have to track the deltas etc. I know, you meant types. :) So where it's important, do use `coerce`, or some `(+ ... 0.0d0)` tricks etc. -- CL is much more a VM than a language, by attitude.

Comment: one can even say, I think, that CL is the most sophisticated assembler, ever!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to compute with a special float format you have to tell it. Usually if you divide double-floats, the result will be a double float. If you have constants, you need to denote them as such.

The Common Lisp standard says: *The result of a numerical function is a float of the largest format among all the floating-point arguments to the function.*.

The interpretation of the following depends on a few things. It depends on how the reader reads numbers. For integers the base can be specified. For floats it depends on the default float format.

```
(let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0)))
```

Let's see how [`*read-default-float-format*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_def.htm) affects it:

```
CL-USER 9 > *read-default-float-format*
SINGLE-FLOAT

CL-USER 10 > (let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0)))
0.33333334
NIL

CL-USER 11 > (setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)
DOUBLE-FLOAT

CL-USER 12 > (let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0)))
0.3333333333333333
NIL
```

Also note that you can specify the type for literal numbers by using an [exponent marker](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_e.htm#exponent_marker):

- d = double-float
- e = float of `*read-default-float-format*`
- f = single-float
- l = long-float
- s = short-float

Example:

```
CL-USER 15 > (setf *read-default-float-format* 'single-float)
SINGLE-FLOAT

CL-USER 16 > (let ((x 1)) (format t "~A~%" (/ x 3.0d0)))
0.3333333333333333D0
NIL
```

You can also *coerce* numbers to a certain type. The function [`COERCE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_coerce.htm#coerce) makes it explicit which type you mean:

```
CL-USER 17 > (let ((x 1))
               (format t "~A~%" (/ (coerce x 'double-float) 3.0)))
0.3333333333333333D0
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks Rainer. I had read about `*read-default-float-format*` and for some stupid reason thought it only applied to how Lisp casted floats that were read from user input.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted you can type `d0` after the number.  E.g.,

```
* 3.0d0
; => 3.0d0
* (type-of 3.0d0)
;=> DOUBLE-FLOAT
```

However, that's the literal notation for a double float, just like `1` is the literal notation for an integer. You can customize the default type of floating point numbers from the reader with [`*read-default-float-format*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_rd_def.htm), and [Rainer Joswig's answer shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354106/1281433).  The declaration

```
(declare (type double-float x))
```

is a promise to the compiler that the value of the variable `x` is a double float.  You're lying to the compiler.   To get a double float, you'll need to either write one as a literal (e.g., `1.0d0`) or convert one with the [`float`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_float.htm) function:

```
* (float 1 0.0d0)
;=> 1.0d0
```

You could also use `coerce` here:

```
* (coerce 1 'double-float)
;=> 1.0d0
```

When there's an option, it's reasonable to compare them.  In SBCL, it turns out that these two options actually compile to the same thing:

```
CL-USER> (disassemble (compile nil (lambda (x) (coerce x 'double-float))))
; disassembly for (LAMBDA (X))
; 039C33E8:       488BD6           MOV RDX, RSI               ; no-arg-parsing entry point
;      3EB:       488B059EFFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-98]          ; #<FDEFINITION object for SB-KERNEL:%DOUBLE-FLOAT>
;      3F2:       B908000000       MOV ECX, 8
;      3F7:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
;      3FA:       FF6009           JMP QWORD PTR [RAX+9]
;      3FD:       CC0A             BREAK 10                   ; error trap
;      3FF:       02               BYTE #X02
;      400:       18               BYTE #X18                  ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
;      401:       54               BYTE #X54                  ; RCX
NIL
```

```
CL-USER> (disassemble (compile nil (lambda (x) (float x 0.0d0))))
; disassembly for (LAMBDA (X))
; 03BC5B18:       488BD6           MOV RDX, RSI               ; no-arg-parsing entry point
;       1B:       488B059EFFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-98]          ; #<FDEFINITION object for SB-KERNEL:%DOUBLE-FLOAT>
;       22:       B908000000       MOV ECX, 8
;       27:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
;       2A:       FF6009           JMP QWORD PTR [RAX+9]
;       2D:       CC0A             BREAK 10                   ; error trap
;       2F:       02               BYTE #X02
;       30:       18               BYTE #X18                  ; INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR
;       31:       54               BYTE #X54                  ; RCX
NIL
```

It sounds like you're trying to do some automatic conversion, and I don't think you're going to find a way to do that.  If you've got a number coming in, and you want a `double-float` you'll have to convert it yourself.  If you want to *check* that a value coming in is a `double-float` you *might* have some luck with declarations, but a type declaration is just a promise to the compiler that something will have a particular type;  this usually means that the compiler can *omit* checks since it's been promised that the value will have a certain type.  That said, you might have some luck;  in SBCL:

```
> (defun foo (x)
    (declare (double-float x))
    (+ x 2.0d0))

> (foo 3)
; The value 3 is not of type DOUBLE-FLOAT.
;    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

You might get different results if you change the safety optimization, though.  If you want to ensure a type check, then use [`check-type`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_check_.htm):

```
> (defun foo (x)
    (check-type x double-float)
    (+ x 2.0d0))

> (foo 3)
; The value of X is 3, which is not of type DOUBLE-FLOAT.
;    [Condition of type SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR]
```

Comment: So if I have a function that doesn't involve any constants at all, then the only way to get it to calculate in double float is to pass it a constant or variable that is already assured to be a double-float? Or is `coerce` something I should use (as @RainerJoswig shows in one of his examples)? Or is `coerce` really only to be used in exceptional cases?

Comment: @mbratch You can use `coerce`, too.  I wasn't sure whether one would be more efficient (`coerce` is certainly more general purpose), but it turns out that in SBCL they compile to the same code.  I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1). I had to give the green check to Rainer because he was the first to point out `coerce` and `*read-default-float-format*` but it was a tough call.

Comment: @mbratch heh, no worries.  I didn't even think of `*default-read-float-format*` until I saw it in his answer.  I like that it's got more about the general process of how floats are read, and what you can do with it.