# Understanding numeric data types in functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

This is a follow-up to the [question on double-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353376/how-to-use-double-float) that I posted earlier. I apologize for what's probably a fundamental Lisp concept, but I haven't grasped it yet.

For this problem, I am using `GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07)`.

Suppose I have the following function, which simply determines square root via Newton's method:

```
(defun sr (n eps)
  (when (>= n 0)
    (do ((x (/ n 2.0) (/ (+ x (/ n x)) 2.0)))
      ((< (abs (- (* x x) n)) eps)
       x))))
```

I can call this as follows:

```
> (sr 2 0.00001)
1.4142157
```

It's giving me single precision float (the default). Makes sense. Due to the lack of precision, if I make `eps` too small, it doesn't function properly and goes into an infinite loop:

```
> (sr 2 0.00000001)
[just sits there...]
```

If I call it with double precision values, I still get single precision results:

```
> (sr 2.0d0 0.00001d0)
1.4142157
> (sr 2.0d0 0.00000001d0)
[just sits there...]
```

But if I redefine my function as follows:

```
(defun sr (n eps)
  (when (>= n 0)
    (do ((x (/ n 2.0d0) (/ (+ x (/ n x)) 2.0d0)))
      ((< (abs (- (* x x) n)) eps)
       x))))
```

I then get double precision no matter how I feed it:

```
> (sr 2 0.00001)
1.4142156862745097d0
```

And now feeding it a smaller `eps` works due to the increased precision:

```
> (sr 2 0.00000001)
1.4142135623746899d0
```

So my question is: is the precision applied by the function totally driven by the precision I specify in the constants it is using in the arithmetic expressions it contains? And if so, what if there were no constants anywhere in the function? What then determines the precision of the calculations and the result?

---

**ADDENDUM**

I just retested this on `SBCL 1.0.57-1.fc17` and I get much more expected results, per the documentation that @JoshuaTaylor quoted in the comment.

Comment: [12.1.4.4 Rule of Float Precision Contagion](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/12_add.htm) says, "The result of a numerical function is a float of the largest format among all the floating-point arguments to the function." That sounds like if you put a double float in, you should get a double float out.  The behavior you're getting is interesting…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I updated my question to indicate that I'm using GNU CLISP 2.49.

Comment: See my answer. This has a setting in CLISP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like this is an incompatibility of CLISP with the ANSI CL Standard.

The ANSI CL standard requires the result to be the largest type of all arguments:

```
CL-USER 20 > (/ 2.0d0 2.0)
1.0D0
```

CLISP gives:

```
[4]> (/ 2.0d0 2.0)
1.0
```

This should be a double float.

**You can change that in CLISP to standard ANSI CL behavior**:

```
[9]> CUSTOM:*FLOATING-POINT-CONTAGION-ANSI*
NIL
[10]> (setf CUSTOM:*FLOATING-POINT-CONTAGION-ANSI* t)
T
[11]> (sr 2.0d0 0.00001d0)
1.4142156862745097d0
```

Now it gives back the desired result.

See the CLISP manual: [12.2.4.1. Rule of Float Precision Contagion](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/num-concepts.html#flocont)

Comment: Ah... I just tried it with SBCL and it actually works as expected. So I agree with this response. :)

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder why the default for `*FLOATING-POINT-CONTAGION-ANSI*` wouldn't be `T`. But that bit of documentation does absolve CLISP of some amount of guilt. ;)

Comment: @Rainer you beat me to it;  I googled for CLISP and 12.1.4.4 and came up with this post that mentions the setting: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/Z3orriYcDT8/Bw57u1MQzYEJ, Well done!

Comment: That section is a very interesting read. And it's fascinating that CLISP developers took that singular stance versus the ANSI default (understandable based upon their explanation).